# jQuery slideshow shows other slides on page load?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the below jQuery script for a slideshow. The problem I'm having is when the page initially loads it briefly flashes the next slides in the queue. How could I prevent this from happening? My code comes from here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow

```
jQuery('#welcome div:gt(0)').hide();
 setInterval(function(){
   jQuery('#welcome :first').hide()
      .next('.slidey').fadeIn()
      .end().appendTo('#welcome');}, 
   5000);


<script src="scripts.js"></script>

<div id="welcome">

<div class="slidey">
    <h1>Example.com</h1>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.example.com/about">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="slidey">

    <h1>The best widgets in the world...</h1>

    <br />

    <a href="http://www.example.com/buywidget">Buy Widget</a>

</div>
```

All, I'm deciding to use this slideshow code instead: http://www.webchief.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-slideshow/index.php It has more functionality...

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the function to the document.ready? (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready( [your functions] )
```

***edit***

if you want to hide the divs use css:

```
style="display:none">
```

Comment: oh ..you mean the other div are like that ..displayed at first, until the script starts? -> see edit: hide divs at first display

Answer (score 0):

Are you on forrst? I saw this posted earlier:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#welcome div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#welcome :first').hide()
            .next('.slidey').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('#welcome');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Also it looks to me like it's not correct usage of `.end()` in this case, I don't know much about it but just read a little and saw an example but isn't this appending only the first element each time?

Comment: my code comes from here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow